# dymnamic or specific product ids not match in my collection magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, product, category

I want to filter dynamic product ids in category and product collection. But the below code is not working.

```
$catIds = array(4);
$notCatIds = array(3,10);
foreach ($specificProductIds as $productId) {
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id='.$productId, null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $catIds))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => $notCatIds))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $productCollection->getSelect()->group('product_id')->distinct(true);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($productCollection->count()); // this is also not work
}
```

Here filter is  not working with `$productId`. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getSize()` function instead of `count()`. and print the  query to check it at database.

```
echo $productCollection->getSelect(); /* for getting query */
```